# Fragment Transaction without commit

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I have seen the code below and unable to figure it out.

```
if (mGoalProgressFragment != null) {
  mCallerFramgent.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(mGoalProgressFragment);
}
mCallerFramgent.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commit();
```

i am not able to understand the part when the if condition fails and `commit()` is called.
and when if condition is true commit is not used for show transaction.

Can anyone help me understand this. because lint shows missing commit for the transaction inside the if selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
...beginTransaction().show(mGoalProgressFragment).commit();
```

call commit method when `mGoalProgressFragment` is not `null` and also remove other statement in which you are calling commit method which is not useful.show useful message in else block when `mGoalProgressFragment` is null.

Comment: can u tell me what beginTransaction.commit() actually does

Comment: `beginTransaction` method is called to start edit operations like adding new framgment,removing fragment from current `FragmentManager` and `commit` method is called to Schedules a task for main thread to close current transaction. you can get more information [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html#beginTransaction%28%29)